# Tensorflow not finding a variable in checkpoint

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

When running the object_detection model to evaluate an existing checkpoint
ssd_mobilent_v2_coco_2018_03_29 from the tensorflow model zoo, I get an error that a variable is not found in the checkpoint:

```
HERE=`pwd`
#MODEL_DIR=$HERE/models/model
cd ~/tf-models/research
#setting a CKPT dir will cause model_main to only eval the model, not train
CONFIG=${HERE}/models/pipeline.config
CKPT=${HERE}/models/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29/model.ckpt
python object_detection/model_main.py \
    --pipeline_config_path=$CONFIG \
    --model_dir=${HERE}/eval_dir2 \
    --alsologtostderr \
    --checkpoint_dir= $CKPT \
    --number_eval_steps=1 \
    --run_once
```

Output:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Key
 FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/layer_19_2_Conv2d_2_3x3_s2_512_depthwise/BatchNorm/beta
 not found in checkpoint
```

However, when I run inspect_checkpoint.py on the checkpoint, I find that variable is present.

```
python inspect_checkpoint.py --file_name models/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29/model.ckpt
```

Output:

```
...lots of vars...
FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV2/layer_19_2_Conv2d_2_3x3_s2_512_depthwise/BatchNorm/beta (DT_FLOAT) [256]
...more...
```

What would make it complain about a missing variable that is apparently in the file(s)?  The pipeline.config file is the one that came with the model, with the paths in it edited as appropriately.  batch_norm_trainable config line was removed (per other forums and the fact that variable does not exist in the model).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake, the space after the --checkpoint_dir= argument caused it to not see the checkpoint_dir.  All better now...